# For loop variable going to hell for seemingly no reason?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, corruption

I have run into what seems to be a very obscure bug.  My program involves looping some code for a long time, and eventually running some functions in the loop.  Weirdly, after I run a specific function, my for loop variable, 'z', jumps from 3200 to somewhere around 1059760811 (it changes every time).  The function does not naturally use the loop variable, so I honestly have no idea what is happening here.

The entire code is too long to paste here, so I will try to paste only the important parts, with the relevant functions first and the for loop after:

```
void enterdata(float dpoint,int num){
        autodata[num] += dpoint;
    }
float autocorr(){
        float autocorrelation = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a<SIZEX; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b<SIZEY; b++)
            {
                if(grid[a][b] == reference[a][b]){autocorrelation++;}
            }
        }
        autocorrelation /= SIZEX*SIZEY;
        autocorrelation -= 0.333333333333;
        return autocorrelation;
    }

for (long z = 0.0; z<MAXTIME; z++)
    {
        for (long k=0; k<TIMESTEP; k++)
        {
            grid.pairswap();
        }
        if (z == autostart_time)
        {
            grid.getreference();
            signal = 1; // signal is used in the next if statement to verify that the autocorrelation has a reference.
        }
        if ((z*10)%dataint == 0)
        {
            if (signal == 1) {
            //!!! this is the important segment!!!
            cout << z << " before\n";
            grid.enterdata(grid.autocorr(),count);
            cout << z << " after\n";
            cout << grid.autocorr() << " (number returned by function)\n";
            count++;
            }
        }
        if (z%(dataint*10) == 0) { dataint *= 10; }
    }
```

From the "important segment" marked in the code, this is my output:

3200 before, 
1059760811 after, 
0.666667 (number returned by function)

Clearly, something weird is happening to the 'z' variable during the function.  I have also become convinced that it is the enterdata function and not the autocorrelation function from tests running each separately.

I have no idea how to fix this, or what is going on.  Help?!?!?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd start with *debugging* it. Since all `enterdata()` does seemingly  is set a value into an array by-given-offset, perhaps your may consider the *offset* is wrong, and therefore walking on your stack variables (and I'm guessing `grid` is on the stack either at, or near, `z`). Where does `count` get its *value* used for the statement `grid.enterdata(grid.autocorr(),count);`?

Comment: What have you tried? stepping into a debugger? adding asserts? running it through valgrind?

Comment: Where does `count` come from?

Comment: In the `for` loop, why is a `long` assigned a floating point value of `0.0`?  Perhaps you wanted `0L`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may have a *Stack Overflow* issue in your `enterdata` function.

Writing to before the array starts or past the end of the array result in undefined behavior, including writing over variables already on the stack.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that was basically it.  I actually had originally not defined the size of the autodata array in its class definition, instead saying 
    float autodata[];
I had done that because I was trying to take a shortcut in defining how many data points I was going to need by just keeping a running count as I got more points and adding those to the array.  I had originally thought that the array would handle this and just add more slots for the new points, but evidently not.

Answer (score 1):

@WhozCraig is right, a stack overwrite by a called function seems the most likely explanation.

You should be able to find out in your debugger how to break on `any change to the memory at address of z`, this will quickly provide an exact diagnosis.

For Visual Studio (for example), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).